# reshaping data frame containing non-numeric value using Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, reshape

I am an R user currently trying to learn python, most of the time during my work I need to reshape dataframe which each cell contains a string. Reshaping is easy for me using `dcast` of `reshape2` package in `R`. I want to do something similarly using the `pandas` package, like the script below:

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame(index=arange(10), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
temp['a'] = 'A'
temp['b'] = 'B'
temp['c'] = 'C'
temp['d'] = 'D'
temp = pd.melt(temp, id_vars=['a','b'])            
temp
pd.pivot_table(temp,index=['a','b'],columns='variable',values='value')
```

It keeps giving me error of `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, I think the `aggfunc` is the issue because the default value is `np.mean`, is there other `aggfunc` that list the cell rather than computing some value for the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.pivot_table(temp,index=['a','b'],columns='variable',values='value',
               aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique()))
```

You can write your own function to `aggfunc`